# Icecast , Ice & Asterisk Integration

Tags: stream, media, asterisk, icecast

Hi there Anyone know how to configure Asterisk so it can stream the output to Icecast server ?
I've been try this guide http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Ices but no luck..i can't solve the problem..can someone tell me how to config Icescast??thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First option use ice2 as described on that page.
- use Jack interface for both icecast and asterisk(mix).
- use EAGI and any streaming app like VLC/ice2/other.

But anyway it take too much delay.

Comment: Thank's That's Help me A lot ;)